# mysql service is not starting after windows update

Tags: windows-10, mysql

I have mysql server 5.6 installed on my system The service was starting properly on startup
but after latest windows-10 update my web app could not connect to mysql, nor did the sqlYog or mysql workbench
So I went to services there I could not found the mysql56 service
and not mysql won't start unless I go to bin and click on mysqld.exe
even after that there no mysql service in services but sqlYog and web app is now connected

Can anyone please tell me how t solve this issue permanently
I had used msi installer to install the service and reinstalling it again is something I really want to avoid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens also to me on every major Windows update : Some applications
stop working, and always the same ones. Windows always disables them when upgrading.

These are all applications that replace some Windows features or
return features that Microsoft phased out or that compete with
Microsoft products.
I would guess that Microsoft does not like them,
or it might perhaps be a honest false positive by Windows Defender.

I'm sorry to say that the only solution I have found is to reinstall or
repair these products, since crucial components were removed.
I agree that this is very annoying.

With at least one such product, its latest version was no longer removed by the
upgrade to Windows 10 version 2004, so it might be that its developers have
removed what has annoyed Windows. Always using the latest
version of these products might in the end get rid of this annoyance.

If you do not want to re-install mysql, check in
*Control Panel > Programs and Features* if right-click on it offers
a Repair or Change option. Such an option might fix the problem without
a total re-installation.

Comment: thank you for taking time and replying to this question
Repair has not effect on the problem
Is there any way I can update this version to new version i have 5.6.12 
Before formatting my system I had 5.7.23 which was running  smooth after updates as well
is there a way to upgrade without affect the data?